# Changing boot sequence for an Orange Pi

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb

My Orange pi boots from a 32 GBs memory card on which I've set up a Raspbian OS. But, the problem is that when I attach my 2 TB external hard disk to the USB slot, it starts looking for the OS on my hard drive at the time of startup.

I need to change the boot sequence and put USB to a lower boot priority but, I'm unable to find the BIOS menu on it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Orange Pi is more of a brand with a variety of boards using different SoCs.  For most however U-Boot will be used, and it is likely actually U-Boot and not the boot rom which is trying the USB storage.  You likely need to connect a serial console, interrupt U-Boot's auto boot and change some setting there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I'm using Orance Pi PC.

Answer (score 4):

Chris Stratton is correct.
Some more details: 
There is no BIOS on ARM architectures.
Your board uses an AllWinner H3 SoC.  This chip has a *very* rudimentary boot process compared to an x86 motherboard.  The BIOS that you typically see on a desktop/laptop computer, with all the menus and selections and such, doesn't exist.
There is no BIOS boot code, and no flash memory to save settings for booting on your Orange Pi.
The H3 has a very limited boot ROM embedded in the chip, that simply reads a block of data from uSD card, starting at 8K, and tries to execute it.  That's all it can do.
If the card contains a boot loader at 8K, then it will load up whatever that boot loader tells it to.  Without a SD card, though, you won't even get anything on the screen.  The H3 itself doesn't even know how to run the USB ports, so there's no way for it to accept keyboard input to change settings, anyway.
I haven't played with Rasbian, but I have tried Armbian.
Right now, I'm trying to get a custom setup on a couple of OPis that can't boot from anything other than the uSD card.  I'm using them for a customer project, and I don't want the customer to be able to plug in a USB key and fubar the software that I've configured on the system.
The U-Boot source code can be downloaded and compiled with custom options.  As far as I know right now (only had these Pis for a couple of weeks, so I'm no expert, by any means) that's the only way to change boot options permanently.
With your current setup, you can (in theory), with a keyboard and display attached, interrupt the boot process during U-Boot initialization, and tell it to boot from the internal card, rather than USB.  This would be a manual process every time you booted, though.
An issue I'm currently having with mine would prevent this, though.  I have no USB support in U-Boot; the keyboard only works after the Linux kernel has loaded, so I can't interrupt the boot process, either on Armbian, or my custom attempts.
Probably your easiest solution, since these are made to run 24/7, is to unplug the USB drive when you're booting it, and plug it in after 5-10 seconds.